# Do I need paper-jsdom-canvas to use the simplify method in paper.js from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, paperjs, jsdom

I'm trying to simplify a hand-drawn path using paper.js' excellent path.simplify method to generate smooth curves after the user finishes drawing. As this is for a non HTML output (TV Telestration) I'm trying to create a microservice in nodejs to take the points and output the control points of the resulting simplified curves.

I tried using paper-jsdom and the method works and doesn't complain but always outputs a single segment with zero coords in all points. I wonder if I'm supposed to be using paper-jsdom-canvas instead to get the appropriate output.

Here is the node module I'm trying to build:

```js
const Path = require('paper').Path
const Point = require('paper').Point
const Project = require('paper').Project

// the next line produces side effects without which 
// the code will not run, but I'm not sure this is the way to go.
let p = new Project() 

function simplify (points) {
  let pts = []
  for (let point in points) {
    let pt = new Point(point.x, point.y)
    pts.push(pt)
  }
  let path = new Path({
    segments: pts,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    fullySelected: false
  })
  path.simplify(10)

  let simplePath = []
  for (const segment of path.segments) {
    // only one segment reaches this point
    // with all zeros in all the parameters
    console.log(segment.path)
    simplePath.push(
      {
        handleIn: { x: segment.handleIn.x, y: segment.handleIn.y },
        handleOut: { x: segment.handleOut.x, y: segment.handleOut.y },
        point: { x: segment.point.x, y: segment.point.y }
      })
    console.log(`
    hi   : (${segment.handleIn.x}, ${segment.handleIn.y})
    ho   : (${segment.handleOut.x}, ${segment.handleOut.y})
    point: (${segment.point.x}, ${segment.point.y})`)
  }
  return simplePath
}
module.exports = simplify
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your error is here:

```
for (let point in points) {
    let pt = new Point(point.x, point.y);
    pts.push(pt);
}
```

If, as I think, the variable `points` contains an array of objects, you should instead use:

```
for (let point of points) {
    let pt = new Point(point.x, point.y);
    pts.push(pt);
}
```

Note the keyword `of` replacing `in` in the for loop.
You are actually looping over the keys and not the values.

Comment: Hi sasensi! Thanks for your help. In fact the loop you mentioned was part of the problem. I had made a change from a forEach to avoid the asyncronous behaviour and had introduced this error. I had a second problem with the serialization of the points I was passing in (they were arrays and not objects) but your answer let the way to the rest of the problem.In fact the loops worked but returned only indexes and then their properties were all undefined.